# JPA EclipseLink - trivial update query exception

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I receive a weird exception when running jpql trivial query:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.createQuery("UPDATE sk_db.Payment p" +" SET p.policyId = ?1 WHERE p.policyId = ?2")
   .setParameter(1, id).setParameter(2, 0)
   .executeUpdate();
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

my schema:

```
create table if not exists SK_DB.Payment
(
  policyId bigserial REFERENCES SK_DB.Policy(id),
  bsoNumber varchar null,
  ....
  PRIMARY KEY(policyId)
```

);

It doesn't matter if I use another fields in update or in select statement I receive a such exception:

```
   Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-
   44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
   Exception Description: Problem compiling 
   [UPDATE sk_db.Payment p SET p.policyId = ?1 WHERE p.policyId = ?2]. 
   [27, 37] The state field cannot be resolved.
   [49, 59] The state field path 'p.policyId' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
```

---

**Solution:**

As @Neil Stockton has mentioned that I used a schema name in query which is incorrect syntax in jpql. Use in jpql queries only entity' names and fields.

Comment: A JPQL query does not use schema/table/column names. It uses entity/field names. That would be found in any JPQL tutorial

Comment: In my case all entity fields the same as db fields. In Payment entity:

private long policyId; 
(with defined setter and getter with this name)

I will pay attention next time about it. Thanks. I don't understand what's wrong with this query..
I changed the 'policyId' to be not a referenced PK, but still the same..

Comment: I already have set it in p.policyId = ?2, it doesn't affect.

Comment: What is "sk_db" ? It is the schema! And I said dont use schema in JPQL.

Comment: When I use without schema prefix I got the following error:

"The abstract schema type 'Payment' is unknown."

My payment entity :
@Entity
@Table(name = "Payment", schema = Constraints.DB_SCHEMA)
public class TPayment implements Serializable

Comment: So raise a BUG on your JPA provider for being incapable of recognising JPQL BULK UPDATE statements. The JPA spec says very clearly what the syntax should be `UPDATE [<candidate-class>] SET item1=value1, item2=value2 [WHERE <filter>]`. There is no schema in there. The JPA spec tells you further details

Comment: Thank you Neil. It's a bug as you said. I used: (UPDATE Payment p SET p.policyId = ?1 WHERE p.id = ?2), So a difficult day :)

Comment: Suggest you put an answer that quotes the bug number on EclipseLink issue tracker and then others who have this can save time

Comment: Fix your question, as you make it appear as if using the schema in a JPQL query should be supported when it is clearly not.  The question you posed and the issue you are hitting is from improper JPQL, not an EclipseLink bug.  EclipseLink can certainly handle schemas in queries, so you might either want to pose a new question  clearly outlining your setup, or modify this one to reflect your actual problem.

Comment: I mean, how can anyone say this is a bug when you haven't even shown the Entity mappings, or how JPA is being told to use the schema.  Do any JPA operations work?

Comment: I forgot to update. You are right @Chris. 
It's not a bug, it's my issue my entity name TPayment and I used as a Payment in query and it works fine now. All other JPA operations work. It's a  bad practice of entities conventions with prefix, but I had no choice cause I have a JAXB classes with the same names without prefix which not stored in db.

Comment: Show the `@Entity` code that map the table Payment